# Difference in Trigger display (Dev Console / Setup>Custom Code>Apex Trigger)

Tags: apex, trigger

Why are some Trigger hidden in the Setup view of all triggers in the org?
The triggers are only visible in the Development console file explorer. What is the filter that is applied here?

Comment: You might have applied some filters on the list of triggers by the first letter. Otherwise, you should see all of them there.

Comment: I was indeed only looking for custom triggers which are not originating from a managed package. My mistake was that there are unmanaged packages present. They contain a namespace but also are not from an installed package. So this way my filter was incorrect because I did not count in unmanaged packages! Thanks. If you want credit pls answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure you have selected "All" in the list view as shown in the picture. This should fetch you all the triggers in your org.[image]

Comment: This could be misleading though. The list view can be customly named so even a list view with the name "All" could have some filters applied.